# Is there any function or way to create Direct3D11CaptureFrame from SoftwareBitmap in UWP C++/CX?

Tags: image-processing, uwp, converters, video-capture, capture

There is a SoftwareBitmap function *CreateCopyFromSurfaceAsync()* which is creating (Windows.Graphics.Imaging.)SoftwareBitmap from (Windows.Graphics.Capture.)Direct3D11CaptureFrame Surface. But is there any possibility to do reverse operation: create Direct3D11CaptureFrame with surface from SoftwareBitmap?

(I am creating a capture session (recording) but in the meanwhile I need to process accesed frames in order to add watermark there)

Comment: According to the document of  [Screen Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture#process-capture-frames), `Direct3D11CaptureFrame` is used to capture frames, and you can get it form capture. So, you can get the `Direct3D11CaptureFrame` object not `SoftwareBitmap` in the beginning. Why do you need to convert `SoftwareBitmap` back to `Direct3D11CaptureFrame`?

Comment: Thank you, @JunjieZhu-MSFT .I am getting Direct3D11CaptureFrame but I wanted to convert it into SoftwareBitmap so I am able to access and modify pixel data. Then I needed to convert it back to Direct3D11CaptureFrame to continue recording process as [described](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture-video). I do not know how may I build video file out of processed data saved in SoftwareBitmaps.

Comment: There is currently no function to create Direct3D11CaptureFrame with surface from SoftwareBitmap, but you can try using [Custom video effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/custom-video-effects#add-your-custom-effect-to-a-camera-video-stream) to achieve a similar effect.